# Display IF output somewhere else PhP

Tags: php

So i have got this code:

```
<?php
$host = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]";
    $rd = "/beta/";
    $beta = "<font color='#6034b1'>BETA</font>";
    if(isset($_COOKIE["fg_beta_user"]) && $_COOKIE["fg_beta_user"]){
    header('Refresh:10;' . $host.$rd);
    echo "<center>You are member of the $beta Project<br>You will be redirected in:<div id='countdown'>10</div><br><progress value='0' max='9' id='progressBar'></progress></center>";}
        else {
    echo "<center>You are not a Member of our $beta Project!<br><a style='border-bottom:1px solid black;' href='switch-to-beta.php'>JOIN NOW</a>";
    }
    ?>
```

Since I have to Place the PhP Script before my `<html>` tag so the `header` refresh works, the `echo` messages get displayed on the very top of the page ( Basically behind my Navbar).
So now my question, is there a way to display the output of this `if` statement via something like a variable somwhere else on the site?

Comment: Yes there is. Just change your `echo "...";` to `$out = "...":` and do a `echo $out;` where ever you want it. Why not just try it?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson because this will only show the output of the variable. it wont show the output of the statement

Comment: If you do what I suggested, instead of `echo "hello";`, do `$out = "hello"; echo $output;`, it will produce the exact same result. The difference is that you can put `echo $output;` where ever you want in your file.

Comment: but as u have maybe seen. I use 2 echo. that means that i cant tell wich of both echos i need to display

Comment: Yes, and you replace both echos with a variable assignment instead, using the same variable. Then it will contain the correct message when you echo it further down. This is exactly like both, correct, answers you've got suggests. I would recommend that you try them out and accept one of them, if they work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you could set the message as a variable,

```
if (YOUR STATEMENT HERE) {
    header();
    $message = "your message";
else {
    $message = "another message";
}
```

Then later in your HTML you could open another PHP tag and echo the variable.

```
<p><?php echo $message; ?></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is quite simple to display your message elsewhere on the page.

```
<?php
$host = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]";
$rd = "/beta/";
$beta = "<font color='#6034b1'>BETA</font>";
if(isset($_COOKIE["fg_beta_user"]) && $_COOKIE["fg_beta_user"]){
header('Refresh:10;' . $host.$rd);
$message = "<center>You are member of the " . $beta . " Project<br>You will be redirected in:<div id='countdown'>10</div><br><progress value='0' max='9' id='progressBar'></progress></center>";
}
    else {
$message = "<center>You are not a Member of our " . $beta . "Project!<br><a style='border-bottom:1px solid black;' href='switch-to-beta.php'>JOIN NOW</a>";
}
?>
```

Then at where ever you want the message to appear add this line of code:

```
<?php
  echo $message;
?>
```